# Can you play Baldur's Gate without a mouse?

Tags: mouse, baldurs-gate

I am currently forced to game on a laptop, and was on verge of viewing life as empty of all meaning, until I remembered Baldur's Gate (and Good old Games). My question is as above: can you play Baldurs Gate without a mouse, and what impact does mouse-less gaming have on your game (if any)?

Comment: Why can't you use the touchpad? The game has pausing feature, so even if sluggish, you should not have problems managing your pointer.

Comment: I will test with touchpad, for some reason I imagined it would not be supported. It might be worth it if can I play BG on the couch and have the laptop on my knees though.

Comment: @gbsod That's not how touchpads work. It's not a matter of the game supporting it or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From memory, there was a legion of keyboard shortcuts, but the only way to interact with objects was by mousing over and clicking them; I am 90% sure there was no way to "tab" between interactive items, and, for better or worse, Baldur's Gate was way before the current age of context sensitive controls.

Even if there was, you'd have to have a way to move your party/characters and control orientation of the formations of your party... I know it's Baldur's Gate, but it's probably more trouble than it's worth :P

You could buy a mini mouse, or go even further back to [NetHack](http://www.nethack.org/), or try out [Dwarf Fortress](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/).

**Edit:** Nowadays one can buy [Baldur's Gate for iPad and Android tablets](http://www.baldursgate.com/) (and [BGII for the iPad](http://www.baldursgateii.com/)), which means you *can* play without a mouse.. just not on the PC versions we know and love ;)

Comment: +1 for DF.  You have to learn keystrokes, there is barely any mouse support at all!

Comment: Time to look for a mini-mouse. NetHack actually does sound interesting, but I have to redeem my gamer's cred though and finish BG first.

Comment: @gbsod - Finish NetHack - that's some *serious* gamer's cred... :)